# Should I have a wrapping function that simply passes arguments through to another function, or assign the other function directly?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

**Edit:** If the answer to this question is simply a matter of style or preference, then that's ok, I'll just pick one. **What I'm really after though** is whether anyone can point out a good reason for why the second way would be a bad choice. They both work.

If I have a reference to a function that takes some parameter(s) and returns the result of calling another function with that same given parameter(s), is it ok to assign the second function to the reference directly rather than having this 
surperfluous 'pass-through' going on?

For example, instead of

```
const fn1 = x => fn2(x)    // (1) pass-through call
```

I would have

```
const fn1 = fn2    // (2) assigning
```

Is there a reason why I should not do this?

One possible reason that I can think of off the top of my head is that I lose control over what parameters are passed to fn2. For example say that fn2 takes two parameters, like so

```
const fn2 = (x, y) => // do something, using y if it's given to produce a different result
```

where the second parameter y is optional.

In (1), when someone calls fn1 with a second argument it's ignored and fn2 is called with the first parameter x only. Ie I have control and force a single argument only to be passed to fn2.

In (2), on the other hand, when someone calls fn1 they're in control of whether one or two arguments are passed through to fn2, since they're actually calling fn2 directly.

Is (2) considered bad? Or maybe it's preferred even?

In case someone wonders why fn1 exists at all when it's just passing through to fn2, it's because I like to do this to improve the clarity of my code. For example, rather than calling

```
createFilledCircle(5)
```

I may call

```
createPositionMarker(5)
```

which simply calls createFilledCircle but makes it clearer what's going on. Ie I would have one of these, and I'm wondering if the second way is ok, preferred, or bad.

```
const createPositionMarker = radius => createFilledCircle(radius) // (1) pass-through call

const createPositionMarker = createFilledCircle // (2) assigning
```

Thanks for any input! :)

Comment: It is not clear what the issue is. What is the coding problem you are having?

Comment: @guest271314 The two ways both work, however I want to avoid writing code that would be considered bad for some valid reason(s). If either way is fine, and it's mostly about style or preference, then that's fine, I'll just pick one. I am wondering though if anyone has a good reason for why the second way would be considered bad. Cheers :)

Comment: "bad" and "good" are subjective terms.

Comment: @guest271314 Yeah, sure. I'm not after style preferences or opinions. I'm after whether there are hard reasons like "(2) is bad because it will break when..."

Comment: @ggorlen I think this is not a question that is opinion-based. I'm after concrete examples of where one way will work but the other one won't. Can you please re-open this question and I will add an example in an answer to prove my point? Thanks